# Search for multiple pattern in same line

Tags: mysql, search

I'm trying to search for different patterns in the same line and then print them in this way.

This is the text:

```
`voices` VALUES (409663,1957,2594,'mech Brands LC - BO GB6: pic - LST  September 2017',NULL,1,0,'2017-09-24 07:35:18',NULL,NULL,1957,0,0,NULL,'2017-09-24 07:35:18');

`others` VALUES (409664,1957,2595,'mech Brands LC - BO NZ6: pic - LST  September 2017',NULL,1,0,'2017-09-24 07:35:18',NULL,NULL,1957,0,0,NULL,'2017-09-24 07:35:18');

`voices` VALUES (409684,628,2622,'Pic Productions Com - pic: perV things September 2017',NULL,1,0,'2017-09-24 07:35:22',NULL,NULL,628,0,0,NULL,'2017-09-24 07:35:22');
```

And I would like to output like this:

```
`voices` - mech Brands LC

`others` - mech Brands LC

`voices` - Pic Productions Com
```

This is what I have tried but it gives me the output in different lines

```
cat file.txt | grep -Pzo "mech Brands LC|Pic Productions Com|\`.*\`"

`invoices`

mech Brands LC

`invoices`

mech Brands LC

`invoices`

Pic Productions Com
```

Could somebody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `sed` for this:

```
sed 's/^\(`[^`]*`\).*\(mech Brands LC\|Pic Productions Com\).*/\1 - \2/' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Or, with POSIX ERE syntax

```
sed -E 's/^(`[^`]*`).*(mech Brands LC|Pic Productions Com).*/\1 - \2/' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/DFZgZv)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `` (`[^`]*`) `` - Group 1: a backtick, 0+ chars other than backticks and a backtick
- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `(mech Brands LC|Pic Productions Com)` - Group 2: either `mech Brands LC` or `Pic Productions Com` substrings
- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `\1 - \2` - the match is replaced with Group 1,  `-`  and Group 2 values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your Help @Wiktor!!! This helped me to solve my problem! :)